# Adding a blog to my Django website

Tags: django, blogs

I have created a website using Django 1.4.3. I'd now like to add a simple blog to it. I'm thinking a good way to do this would be to add a new blogging app to my existing Django project? Are there any simple Django blog apps that I could "drop in" to my existing project to achieve this?

Also, I have an existing blog on Posterous that I have exported (a set of folders and a wordpress_export_1.xml file.)

It would be great if I could somehow import this into my new Django based blog.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps

**django-basic-apps** (formerly django-basic-blog) has a blog app (and included apps to help said blog app) that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/microblog-kitchen-sink/ . It is a free courses by Kenneth Love.